# How can I change the color of my cursor in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, xfce, 12.04

There are many similar-sounding questions, so let me emphasize: I only want to change the color of my cursor; I do not want to change the color of my text.  If it helps, however, my normal text color is white.

I realize xterm allows this, but I prefer to stick with gnome-terminal.  There does not seem to be a preference in the menus.

System particulars:  Ubuntu 12.04 alpha 2, Gnome Terminal 3.2.1, XFCE desktop

Comment: I just switched to XFCE Terminal instead, which allows this and seems to be a superior terminal in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

Manual exist though. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/setterm.1.html

gconf-editor /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/default_settings may have to set a new key as a string and color configuration.

Answer (score 4):

There's an escape sequence for that:

```
echo -ne '\e]12;#ffcc00\a'
```

or you can also use symbolic color names:

```
echo -ne '\e]12;pink\a'
```

Comment: "pink" doesn't work for me (gnome-terminal with TERM=xterm-256color) but the "#ffcc00" version does.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to the best of my knowledge there is not an option as of yet to do this.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me... The answer is "no".